# Return element of pair with perfect forwarding

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype, decltype-auto

I want to write a function that will evaluate some expression that returns a pair (possibly as a reference, and possibly containing references) and returns the second element, but which forwards references rather than copying them.

Here's an example that doesn't quite work:

```cpp
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename F>
decltype(auto) foo(F&& func)
{
    return get<1>(std::forward<F>(func)());
}

pair<int, int> value_of_values()
{
    return make_pair(2, 3);
}

pair<int &, int &> value_of_refs()
{
    static int x = 4;
    static int y = 5;
    return pair<int &, int &>(x, y);
}

pair<int, int> &ref_of_values()
{
    static pair<int, int> p(6, 7);
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    cout << foo(value_of_values) << '\n';
    cout << foo(value_of_refs) << '\n';
    cout << foo(ref_of_values) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is with `foo(value_of_values)`: `value_of_values` returns a prvalue, but `get<1>` returns an rvalue reference, so foo returns an rvalue reference to a temporary that promptly disappears.

I know I can probably do some template metaprogramming with `decltype` to distinguish the case where the function return value is a prvalue containing a non-reference (which must be returned as a non-reference) from the other cases, but is there a more elegant solution?

(using `std::forward<F>(func)().second` instead of `get<1>(...)` doesn't help: if it's parenthesised one gets exactly the same problem because member access on a prvalue is an xvalue, causing `decltype(auto)` to infer `int &&`, and if it's not parenthesized then the `ref_of_values` case returns a copy instead of a reference because of the semantics of `decltype` for unparenthesized member access expressions).

Answer (score 4):

> I know I can probably do some template metaprogramming with decltype
> to distinguish the case where the function return value is a prvalue
> containing a non-reference (which must be returned as a non-reference)
> from the other cases, but is there a more elegant solution?

You can first use universal reference to receive the return value of `func`, and then decide whether to move construct the object according to whether it is an rvalue.

```
template<typename F>
decltype(auto) foo(F&& func)
{
  auto&& x = std::get<1>(std::forward<F>(func)());
  using T = decltype(x);
  if constexpr (std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T>)
    return x;
  else
    return std::remove_reference_t<T>(std::move(x));
}
```

Comment: If `func` returns a `std::pair<int &&, int &&>` I think this will move-construct rather than forwarding the rvalue reference.

Comment: There is no harm with move construction. Since `func` returns a prvalue, it can be moved freely. If we still forward `int&&`, there may be a risk of dangling reference.

Comment: For `int` move construction is fine. But `int` is just an example I used, and for a generic type there might not even be a move constructor.

Comment: For copy-only objects, `std::remove_reference_t<T>(std::move(x))` will call its copy constructor. Since you are forwarding an r-value reference, there is no reason not to move it to a new object, because you cannot guarantee that it will not expire.

Comment: When I said "might not even be a move constructor" I was thinking of the case where isn't a move OR copy constructor. If `func()` returns an rvalue reference (rather than a prvalue) then there isn't anything that will expire when `foo` returns that hasn't already expired.